# Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: invalid tag "***/e2bdy:": invalid reference format

Tags: docker, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm using github action to build&push docker image, but it failed with err.

[errors screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lprym.png)

```
buildx failed with: ERROR: invalid tag "***/e2bdy:": invalid reference format
```

Is there anything wrong with my action.yml ? Local build is successful.

```yaml
name: e2bdy docker
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - version.py
      - .github/workflows/build.yml
      - requirements.txt
      - dockerfile

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build Docker Image
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@main

      - name: Release version
        id: release_version
        run: |
          app_version=$(cat version.py |sed -ne "s/APP_VERSION\s=\s'v\(.*\)'/\1/gp")
          echo "app_version=$app_version" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Set Up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set Up Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Login DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build Image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: docker
          file: dockerfile
          build-args: |
            GITHUB_TOKEN=${{ secrets.RELEASE_TOKEN }}
          platforms: |
            linux/amd64
            linux/arm64
          push: true
          tags: |
            musnows/e2bdy:latest
            musnows/e2bdy:${{ env.app_version }}
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.2
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV LANG="C.UTF-8" \
    TZ="Asia/Shanghai" \
    PGID=0 \
    PUID=0 \
    BDY_SECRET_KEY="" \
    BDY_APP_KEY="" \
    BDY_APP_NAME="e2bdy" \
    ENCRYPT_UPLOAD=1 \
    SYNC_INTERVAL=600

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/
COPY ./config /app/config

VOLUME [ "/app/config" ]

CMD [ "python","main.py" ]
```

github repo：https://github.com/musnows/encrypt2bdy/tree/main

At first,I used `${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/e2bdy:latest` for image name, it failed with this err.So I tryed to use my username instead of `action secrets`,but it still failed in build docker image

Comment: env.app_version did not get defined.

Comment: I set it in github repo action variables, APP_VERSION = 0.1.0

Comment: Did you verify that it got set? Because the build action error message says that it didn't.

Comment: I did set it up, I don't know why it didn't take effect.

Comment: It seems like I didn't set version.py in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this yaml works

```
name: Docker Image CI
#触发器设置
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

#项目任务，任务之间可以并行调度
jobs:
  build:
  #选择云端运行的环境
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    #uses代表使用一个模块，此处使用的是checkout模块，将github项目文件导入到当前环境中
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    #使用with跟在后面来为前面的模块输入参数
      with:
        submodules: 'true'
    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
    - name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
     # 这里用到了github的secrets功能，避免账户和密码随仓库泄露
       username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
    - name: Build and push
      # 导入这个模块来完成自动编译和推送
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
          context: .
          push: true
          #在这里通过加入需要编译的平台和前面配好的QEMU，buildx来达到多平台编译
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm
          #指定用户/仓库名
          tags: musnows/e2bdy:latest
    - name: Docker Hub Description
      # 这里是通过md文件自动生成dockerhub描述的模块，也可以不需要
      uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v3
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        repository: musnows/e2bdy
        readme-filepath: ./README.md
```

The old one fiailed because I didn't set [version.py](https://github.com/musnows/encrypt2bdy/blob/main/version.py) correctly

```py
# the right one
APP_VERSION = 'v0.1.0'
# err!
APP_VERSION = '0.1.0'
```

Now I'm using this yaml,which cloud push docker images with latest & version in `version.py`

```yaml
name: Docker Image CI
#触发器设置
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

# 项目任务，任务之间可以并行调度
jobs:
  build:
  # 选择云端运行的环境
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    #u ses代表使用一个模块，此处使用的是checkout模块，将github项目文件导入到当前环境中
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    # 使用with跟在后面来为前面的模块输入参数
      with:
        submodules: 'true'
    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
    - name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
    # 这里用到了github的secrets功能，避免账户和密码随仓库泄露
       username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
    # 设置当前的发行版本tag
    - name: Release version
      id: release_version
      run: |
        app_version=$(cat version.py |sed -ne "s/APP_VERSION\s=\s'v\(.*\)'/\1/gp")
        echo "app_version=$app_version" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    # 开始构建镜像
    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        file: dockerfile
        build-args: |
          GITHUB_TOKEN=${{ secrets.RELEASE_TOKEN }}
        platforms: |
          linux/amd64
          linux/arm64
          linux/arm
        push: true
        # 指定用户/仓库名
        tags: |
          ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/e2bdy:latest
          ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/e2bdy:${{ env.app_version }}
    # 这里是通过md文件自动生成dockerhub描述的模块，也可以不需要
    - name: Docker Hub Description
      uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v3
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        repository: musnows/e2bdy
        readme-filepath: ./README.md
```